# How to send input to stdin of a process created with Command AND then capture output (and status)

Tags: rust

I wish to create a child process using Command, feed it stdin from another child I create AND then wait for and capture output.

I have seen other questions and answers about one or the other, but not both.

The order I am trying is:

- Create the destination child command, stdin as Piped()
- Spawn the child using spawn() and get Child back
- get 'stdin' field from Child to use with buffer writer
- spawn source of data process with stdout Piped()
- loop over the output of source writing stdout to the stdin of destination
- then try and capture output of destination with wait_with_output()

This last step doesn't compile as it says Child object is moved (consumed) when I get stdin for it.

Playground [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=455ed8c04aadd23ccc05ae1658ef9c91)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to take ownership of the `dest_child.stdin` pipe to give the object to `BufWriter::new`. Since the pipe is inside an `Option`, you can use [`Option::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) to move it out without leaving `dest_child` "partially moved". Another issue with your code is that `dest.stdin` must be piped rather than inherited, otherwise `dest_child.stdin` will simply remain `None`. With those changes, your code compiles and runs ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=329c190b17ea499cc62ee06da0f745f5)).

Note, however, that it is not necessary to manually transfer data from one process to another, the OS is perfectly capable of doing that on its own. For example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0b049f2cceb67fe815334bbe0886c3d5)):

```
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};

fn main() {
    let mut dest = Command::new("wc")
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();
    let _source = Command::new("ls")
        .stdout(dest.stdin.take().unwrap())
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();
    let dest_output = dest.wait_with_output().unwrap();

    match dest_output.status.code() {
        Some(0) => println!("OK: {}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&dest_output.stdout)),
        Some(code) => println!("Error {}", code),
        None => {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I copied the code that copies it across from another answer. You're is much more succinct and elegant. Appreciated.